# Об употреблении кавычек

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделять кавычками словосочетание "воздушный карман", если первый раз оно идет после слов "так называемый", а далее по тексту просто повторяется несколько раз?

Например: Если таких воздушных карманов много, поток воды в трубопроводе может полностью прекратиться.

Comment: В тексте лучше использовать единообразное написание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как подходить к вопросу в принципе, это важно.

Вначале проверяем этот воздушный карман по всем словарям;

если не находим, тогда допускаем, что его придумал автор, и тогда при первом упоминании (при описании явления и словах "так называемый") кавычки не ставим и шрифтовое выделение не обязательно, но

кавычим "воздушный карман" по всему тексту далее.

Однако ж, словарями термин обнаружен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Казалось бы, можно не кавычить вообще, но... словарь - ВЕТРОВ! - уж больно специфическое издание.

Поэтому исходим из того, для какой аудитории предназначен текст: продвинутым в аэродинамике ничего не кавычим, ни разочка,

для широкой же публики ставим кавычки во всех случаях за исключением первого, с "так называемым".

Вот исправленный по моему редакторскому разумению текст, из которого в вопрос вынесено предложение:

> Когда воздух собирается в высоких точках трубопровода, он частично
>   перекрывает его проходное сечение. Появляется так называемый воздушный
>   карман, который снижает расход воды. В результате увеличивается расход
>   энергии, необходимой на её перекачку. Если таких «воздушных карманов»
>   много, поток воды в трубопроводе может полностью прекратиться.
>   Вытеснение и перемещение «воздушных карманов» может привести к
>   внезапному изменению скорости потока воды, вызывающему гидроудары и
>   повреждения труб. В местах «воздушных карманов» ускоряется коррозия
>   стенок трубы, повреждаются измерительные устройства и неустойчиво
>   работают регулирующие клапаны.

У Розенталя мне не удалось найти примеров с повторяющимся словом или словосочетанием; найден лишь один прецедент у Паустовского (засинён):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно ли выделять кавычками словосочетание "воздушный карман", если
>   первый раз оно идет после слов "так называемый"

Варианты возможного выделения при первом упоминании:

так называемый "воздушный карман"...

так называемый **воздушный карман**...

так называемый *воздушный карман*…

> а далее по тексту просто повторяется несколько раз

При дальнейшем упоминании этого термина выделение его каким-либо образом не требуется, например:

> Если таких воздушных карманов много, поток воды в трубопроводе может
>   полностью прекратиться.

Comment: После т.н. кавычки обычно не ставятся.  Исключение составляют случаи, когда эти слова употреблены в необычном или ироническом значении".Розенталь. Справочник по орфографии и пунктуации, параграф 60, п. 2, примечание.

Answer (score 1):

Если это понятие общепринятое, то брать его в кавычки **не нужно** и при первом упоминании: в этом случае выражение "*так называемый*" просто обращает внимание неосведомлённой части читателей на термин, важный для понимания дальнейшего текста (дополнительно, в частности, для обозначения конечной границы приводимого понятия, можно при первом упоминании применить курсив), и не может быть использовано для введения собственного нового термина. Кавычки же могут понадобиться только для первой ссылки на оригинальную (напр. впервые введённую) терминологию из другого источника.